# alfresco start workflow directly from document library

Tags: workflow, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I use ALfresco 5.2 community edition and I need to start a custom workflow directly from the document details page, though a custom button/action.

I've already searched the web and Stackoverflow community, the nearest thing I've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252572/alfresco-linking-directly-to-workflow) but I can't figure it out.

I would like to use the default page for the workflow `http://localhost:8080/share/page/site/my-site/start-workflow` with the dropdown already selected.

How can I do that?

Comment: You need to customer startworkflow.js and other few components in share side. How much you're allowed to customise Share ?

Comment: I can customise it for all I want. What components do I have to change and how do I change them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this customization, like you thought, with a custom button/action. I create a js method that redirect to "start-workflow" page, similar to base method on actions.js. Then i customize start-workflow.js taking my definition and work is done. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom action like Start X Workflow and write backend custom action java logic to start workflow.